# Error Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'CameraViewVS' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on. parallel.for

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0

I have a timer to verify one condition every time and show pop up form only once if the condition is verified. I want to verify in parallel all instances, so i used parallel.for, but i have this error "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'CameraViewVS' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."  in line " frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;"

this is my code:

```
public void timer1_Tick(object source, EventArgs e)               
{
    Parallel.For(0, nbre, l =>
        {
            cameraInstanceList[l].Start();
            if (cameraInstanceList[l].MoveDetection == true)
            {
                //show the the form S once 
                foreach (Form S in Application.OpenForms)
                {
                    var frm = S as Formes.CameraViewVS;
                    if (frm != null && frm.IP == cameraInstanceList[l].adresse)
                    {
                        cameraInstanceList[l].MoveDetection = false;
                        frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                        frm.Activate();
                        return;
                    }
                }

                f1 = new Formes.CameraViewVS(cameraInstanceList[l],
                adresseIPArray[l]);
                f1.Show(this);

            }

        }               
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Most properties on WinForm object instances need to be accessed from the thread that they were created on.  You can use the Control.InvokeRequired property to determine if you need to use the control (or form) Invoke method to execute the code on the UI thread.

It is also a good practise to create most WinForm controls on the main UI thread, and not on any thread pool threads. In WinForms applications, you can use the `SynchronizationContext` to ensure some code, such as creating a form, is called on the UI thread.

**EDIT:** changed so that the method doesn't return after movement detected.

```
public void timer1_Tick(object source, EventArgs e)                         
{          
    // assume this is being called on the UI thread, and save the thread synchronization context
    var uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    Parallel.For(0, nbre, l =>          
        {          
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(250);  // <--- sleep for 250 ms to avoid "busy" wait

                cameraInstanceList[l].Start();          
                if (cameraInstanceList[l].MoveDetection == true)          
                {       
                    // capture instances used in closures below
                    var cameraInstance = cameraInstanceList[l];
                    var ipAdresse = adresseIPArray[l];

                    //show the the form S once                             
                    foreach (Form S in Application.OpenForms)                            
                    {
                        var frm = S as Formes.CameraViewVS; 
                        if (frm != null)
                        {
                            // create delegate to be invoked on form's UI thread.
                            var action = new Action(() =>
                                {
                                    if (frm.IP == cameraInstance.adresse) 
                                    { 
                                        cameraInstance.MoveDetection = false; 
                                        frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal; 
                                        frm.Activate(); 
                                    }
                                };

                            if (frm.InvokeRequired)
                                frm.Invoke(action);  
                            else
                                action();

                            continue; // <--- go back to the top of the while loop
                                      //      and wait for next detection
                        }
                    }

                    // create delegate to create new form on UI thread.
                    var createNewFormCallback = new SendOrPostCallback((o) =>
                        {
                            f1 = new Formes.CameraViewVS(cameraInstance, ipAdresse); 
                            f1.Show(this);  
                        };    

                    // and invoke the delegate on the ui thread
                    uiContext.Send(createNewFormCallback, null); 
                }            
            } 
        }
        );
}
```

Comment: It miss one argument in uiContext.Send(createNewFormCallback, xxx), i added "line " + l.ToString(), but when i execute it show me just one pop up, i'm newer in using thread, so if you could please give me some link of good tutorials, thank you again

Comment: @Ostorlabi Thanks for pointing that out.  Second param should be `null`.  I recommend that you use the debugger to place breakpoints after `MovedDetection == true`, or use Debug.WriteLine to log the flow of execution to see what is working and what isn't.

Comment: I add Debug.WriteLine("error"); after  MovedDetection == true, to log the flow but i don't see any thing, is there a file saved?

Comment: @Ostorlabi If you are running this in the using Visual Studio debugger, you should be able to see this in the Output Window.  
See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815788 and the standalone DebugView at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647

Comment: @Thomas: Thank you, I saw the Output Window, it displays the message "error" just the first time when there is move, and even if the movedDetection == true for the other instance or also the same instance concerned, it don't display onother time "error". Whereas, when i tested with the initial code without parallel, it displays "error" at each time there is a move.

Comment: @Ostorlabi Thats' because you have a return statement, which means that the camera will no longer be monitored.  If you want it to keep on being monitored, I have adjusted my answer.

Comment: I have adjusted my answer to include a while loop (with a Thread.Sleep so that the loop does not busy wait), which means each thread will continue to run instead of exiting.  To this effect, the `return` statement has been replaced with a `continue`.

Comment: I used return, to display the same pop up only once, eventhough it will display the same pop up at each time there a move.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas is very close to right answer ,Because Every Control runs in a different thread .You should just write a code for context-switching of resources which is being used by Controls 
 Thread ..Don't worry you have a lot of facility for this in c sharp.Just use BeginInvoke and Invoke and i hope you would be able to resolve your problem.Write this in place of your old code block ..

```
                 var action = new Action(() =>
                            {
                                if (frm.IP == cameraInstance.adresse) 
                                { 
                                    cameraInstance.MoveDetection = false; 
                                    frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal; 
                                    frm.Activate(); 
                                }
                            };

                        if (frm.InvokeRequired)
                            frm.BeginInvoke(action);  
                        else
                            frm.Invoke(action);
```

Comment: I wrote, this, it can display more than one pop up, but the problem that they aren't synchrone with a move, I explain, when there is a move in one camera it is displayed but if there is a move at the second and the third camera at the same time of the first, the second and the third aren't diplayed until i close the first. But if i don't use parallel.for (just simple boucle for), if you see my first code, it works fine and it's faster than parallel.for.